# Chrome shows wrong time zone

Tags: google-chrome, time-zone

In Windows my time zone is set to UTC+2:00 Jerusalem

But several websites think I'm in UTC. And I see that Chrome reports my timezone as UTC. When I try this in my console

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

I get "UTC"

Though I can't for the life of me find any setting in Chrome that keeps it's own timezone.

I'm using WIndows 10. Here's the `navigator.userAgent`

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
```

If I run `tzutil /g` in the command line, I get:

```
Israel Standard Time
```

There are extensions that let me change the timezone. But I'd rather solve the issue. So I can help other clients with similar issues.

Thanks!

Comment: some websites do not show times in local time zone of the user but the raw data. nothing to do the with the browser. some web apps will have a time settings how you want to have the data shown.

Comment: Hi Thanks. Please realize that the issue is in the `Intl.DateTimeFormat()`. Not related to any specific web site

Comment: Is the problem always with the same websites?

Comment: Hi. I encounter the issue mainly on sites that use the `antd` date picker. but like I said, the problem is in `Chrome` / `JavaScript`. `antd` I believe is only the symptoms. Thanks.

Comment: Hi all. Now I see something else. Unsure whether it was always this way or not. In Gmail I see emails coming in, with the time wrong. i.e. an email that was really sent at 15:30 pm shows up 13:30. Is this the same issue. whats wrong here and what can I fix? Thanks!

Comment: I realise this is years old but I have the same issue. If I do your timezone test I get the correct tz, "Pacific/Auckland", in Chrome and "UTC" in Firefox. Also, like you, some web applications (such at email and timetracker) clearly think I'm in UTC. I'm guessing it's due to an extension I've installed although I can't remember having installed any recently. The start of the problem seemed to coincide with me restarting the machine.

Comment: Hmm OK. I have found the answer to the problem I was having. My problem was with respect to Firefox, it appears that when you set the privacy.resistFingerprinting option to true then the browser advertises itself as being in UTC and so the content is shown as being in UTC. See here for more details https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1198372